# I cannot initially hide(); my span tag

Tags: jquery

I have a loader animated gif that I want to hide and show during my ajax request.

this is my loader html code.

```
<span id="loader"><img src="images/icons/ajax-loader.gif" alt="loader" /></span>
```

I want to initially hide it with this

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#loader').hide()
        });
    </script>
```

however it still shows up until until my ajax function is actually run and then hides it. but I want to hide it at startup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<span id="loader" style="display: none">...</span>
```

Answer (score 3):

It isn't being hidden until your document is loaded and "ready". To prevent it from showing up at all, include this CSS before your `<body>`:

```
<style>
#loader { display: none; }
</style>
```

Answer (score 3):

Add the style `display:none;` to the span in the markup.

```
<span id="loader" style="display:none;">
    <img src="images/icons/ajax-loader.gif" alt="loader" />
</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

did u use asp.net? maybe progress panel trigger it

$('#loader') is just a content inside

try

```
$('#loader').parent().hide()
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#loader').css("display","none");
    });
</script>
```